# Update, Join and Select 2 tables to calculate a formula

Tags: mysql, select, join, sql-update

I have an **'Amount' per day**  shown on **tableB** :

[image]

And I want to calculate the amount per '**Description**' (they are 5 in total) in **tableA**:

[image]

So, my formula should be:

```
tableA.Amount = tableB.Amount * tableA.Numbers / sum(tableA.Numbers) 
where tableA.date = tableb.date
group by tableA.Description
```

In mySQL I am using this code:

```
update tableA
join tableB
on tableB.date = tableA.date  
set tableA.amount = tableB.amount * (select tableA.Numbers from tableA group by tableA.date, tableA.Description) / sum(tableA.Impressions)
where tableA.campaign = 'Autumn'
;
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It does not work? Please provide more info, like syntax error in your query. The syntax looks strange to me. How did you find this query??

Comment: @Pieter21 Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tableA' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I think your inner query results in something too complex (like lists of grouped records) for a simple update statement. I think it is back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the logic to the `from` clause.  It is a little hard to figure out exactly what you want to do, but I think it is something like this:

```
update tableA a join
       tableB b
       on b.date = a.date join 
       (select a.date, sum(a.Numbers) as sumn
        from tableA a
        group by a.date
       ) da
       on a.date = da.date join
    set a.amount = b.amount * a.Numbers / da.sumn
where a.campaign = 'Autumn';
```

I have no idea what the filter on `campaign` is doing, because it is not in your sample data.

Comment: Good idea. I had to modify it to make it work. But still, it helped me a lot !

Comment: Modifications had to be made based on the previous code. I am not saying that you made a mistake. Just to clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

If the syntax is modified as in the example below, it probably should work. It would be helpful to fix if the error is provided.

UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
WHERE conditions;